# How to create HDR images using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, hdrimages

I am using opencv 3.0 version which has support for creating HDR images and trying to produce an HDR image using three images at different exposure.
And i found this tutorial of opencv.

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db7/tutorial_hdr_imaging.html#gsc.tab=0

Its easy to understand but it takes paramter like exposure times for images.
How do i will get this exposure time ? I have only images. Do any one has tried it already ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you get the images?  Do they have metadata?

Comment: I have just clicked those images from my mobile, Is there any way i can get the metadata ?

Comment: yes there is, but that is a different question

Comment: So how can get that, using images ? or some other way ? can i use opencv to get the information ?

Comment: over all i want to HDR image

Comment: You need to have the exposure times. Make sure ISO is constant on your camera and set the exposure time manually for each shot.

Answer (score -2):

Image exposure time is in EXIF data. In the explorer window right click the image, go to properties, you will see some of the EXIF data including exposure time if the image has that data.

or you can write a program to extract metadata to a txt file. I used python exifread() to read exposure time.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead